# Reply link wordpress doesn't work

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm trying to put a reply link on my comments.php form and it doesn't work. It only refreshes my page!

The code i'm using is as follows:

```
<div class= replay_text">
<font size="-1"><strong><a href="<?php comment_reply_link( array ( 'reply_text' => 'Replay alt="Reply">' ) ); ?>">Reply</a></strong></font></div>
```

Someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very much php, but I think the problem is that you forgot to open `"` and you, on php, said `reply_text` and not `replay_text`. Here is the correct one:

```
<div class= "reply_text">
<font size="-1"><strong><a href="<?php comment_reply_link( array ( 'reply_text' => 'Replay alt="Reply">' ) ); ?>">Reply</a></strong></font></div>
```

Comment: correcting language errors have notihing to do with worpdress internal functions and fixing issue :(

Comment: Sorry, I thought it could be only language errors... I don't want him to stick searching for the error knowing that it is only the language

Comment: He just uses a function in a way, that it should not being used. Also sending arguments in array in the way, that I just dont get, what he is doing.

Comment: Try looking the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_reply_link

Answer (score 0):

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1371

Check how comment_reply_link should be used. Using it as anchor source isn't greatest idea, and I have seen worse, but You wil not get with tah to anything.

Instead in anchor target use it like this, between other html elements:

```
<?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('add_below' => $add_below, 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
```